# how to route client HTTP requests over multiple NIC with libcurl

Tags: http, ubuntu, libcurl, nic

On an Ubuntu machine, I wonder if there is a way to *route* specific HTTP requests to the same server - let's say, a video provider - over multiple network interface cards (NICs).

I've heard about [link bonding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation), but this seems to be outside of control of applicative code. Could libcurl be used to perform this task ?

I think I can inspect system configuration to *detect* multiple NICs, but then how to *translate* an address so that it will be read from a specific interface ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the outgoing interface depends on your routing table.

Curl supports [selecting the outgoing interface](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).

```
--interface <name>

Perform an operation using a specified interface. You can enter interface name, IP address or host name. An example could look like:

 curl --interface eth0:1 http://www.netscape.com/

If this option is used several times, the last one will be used.
```

If you want to use several interfaces for the same operation (like in the article you mentioned), you need the package `ifenslave-2.6`. Google lists many tutorials how to use it.